# Docker accept expired certificate on server/host for Windows

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, x509

When using

```
docker login mycustomwebsite.com
```

I run into issue

```
x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

So, the certificate on mycustomwebsite.com is actually expired. I'm ok with that since I will update it later and right now I don't have access to it.

How can I tell docker & docker-compose to accept expired certificate? 
Additionally, how can I completely disable certificate validation if necessary?

I've search SO for answers, closest was to use "--insecure-registry" but such option does not exist for my version or for versions 1.3.0+ (unless I'm completely confused with how insecure-registry was supposed to work)

ps:

***Docker*** version 18.03.0-ce / ***Docker-compose*** version 1.20.1 / windows 7

ps2: didn't find solution that works, had to wait until I was able to renew certificates

Comment: Insecure registry should work in your case. Have you modified deamon.json file ans also used —insecure-registry option while using docker login ??  it is properly explained on : https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/.      Only thing to confirm that it ignores expired certs too

Comment: like I said, when I try to use login command, it tells me it doesn't know such option or such flag. Yes, I did create daemon.json.